# Access textContent of hidden table cell

Tags: javascript

I'm working with an html form that displays rows of data only for data elements that are found with a submitted value in the database.  For example, the following table row will be toggled off ( style="display:none" ) if there is no value found in the database for 'Seizures_Type', and WILL be displayed if there is a value found in the database.

The javascript works to concatenate values from several similar fields on the form and store in a single field, id="medalert".

When the script runs, it fails if it tries to access a field that is in the display:none state.

What would be a good way to allow the script to run fully, even if it encounters these hidden elements?

```
<a href="#" onClick="buildMedAlert();">Build</a>


<tr style="display:none"> 
    <td title="seizures type">Seizures Type</td>
    <td></td>
    <td id="par_med_seizures_type"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk_med_seizures_type"></td>
</tr>

<tr style="display:none"> 
    <td title="seizures type">Seizures Medication</td>
    <td></td>
    <td id="par_med_seizures_medication"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk_med_seizures_medication"></td>
</tr>



function buildMedAlert(){
     var retval = "";

    if (document.getElementById('par_med_seizures_type').textContent.length>0) {
        retval += "Type: " + document.getElementById('par_med_seizures_type').textContent;
    }

    if (document.getElementById('par_med_seizures_medication').textContent.length>0) {
        retval += "Medication: " + document.getElementById('par_med_seizures_medication').textContent;
    }

    document.getElementById('medalert').value=retval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I add the missing field medalert, it does not fail in neither Chrome nor IE10

```js
function buildMedAlert() {
  var retval = "";

  if (document.getElementById('par_med_seizures_type').textContent.length > 0) {
    retval += "Type: " + document.getElementById('par_med_seizures_type').textContent;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('par_med_seizures_medication').textContent.length > 0) {
    retval += "Medication: " + document.getElementById('par_med_seizures_medication').textContent;
  }
  document.getElementById('medalert').value = retval;
}
```

```html
 <a href="#" onClick="buildMedAlert();">Build</a>

<table>
  <tr style="display:none">
    <td title="seizures type">Seizures Type</td>
    <td></td>
    <td id="par_med_seizures_type">Some type</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk_med_seizures_type">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="display:none">
    <td title="seizures type">Seizures Medication</td>
    <td></td>
    <td id="par_med_seizures_medication">Some med</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk_med_seizures_medication">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="medalert">
```

Comment: Of course, because you are adding a text element, and accessing it's content, you didn't do the following above, so there was no medalert element to access it's text contents. You still should make sure your cell is visible before making any workaround on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a condition to check if the row is visible, give it an ID (since I don't believe you want to work on every  element in the code) and then, make sure to check if the element is visible, like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('element');
 if(element.style.display != 'none'){
}
```

The thing is that you cannot access the contents of a hidden element since it is hidden and so, the javascript doesn't recognize it. You have to make sure the element is not hidden.

Comment: This is actually not true